# Meaning of 「手伝ってくれるのとちがうのか」

Tags: meaning

I'm reading the following dialogue, pretty straightforward:

> A：ずいぶんあわてて、どうしたんだ。
>   B：昨日出さなければいけない報告書を忘れていたんだ。
>   A：それは大変だ。まあ頑張れよ。
>   B：なんだ、手伝ってくれるのとちがうのか。
>   A：それは、君の仕事だろう。

I have problems understanding the full meaning of 手伝ってくれるのとちがうのか。 I understand 手伝ってくれる and ちがう as separate, independent things. But I don't get the full sentence, though I suspect the overall meaning might be something along the lines of 手伝ってくれない？

Comment: I think it's like 「なんだ、手伝ってくれるんじゃないのか。」"What, you mean you're not gonna help?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

の as in 手伝ってくれるの is so called a nominalizer, which turns a clause into technically a noun. And, (noun) と ちがう means "be different from (noun)".

Now, when you embed the 手伝ってくれるの, which is technically a noun, into "(noun)と ちがう", you get something like "it's different from a situation that you help me".